# How to do Application wise bettery usage/drain in android

Tags: android

i got many stack overflow for the battery info mobile.but i can't get any info on stack overflow for the application wise get battery info.my mean to which application most use the power and voltage in android.please anybody can suggest me to how to do programming for battery usage.

[image]

I want battery status output as above application wise battery drain/usage in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some very nice posts [Optimizing Battery Life](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html) from Google. There are couple of aspects to learn. Another posts describe [Transferring Data Without Draining the Battery](https://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best sources you could get are the ones from android developer trainnig section:

**Optimizing Battery Life**
http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html

**Transferring Data Without Draining the Battery**
http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/index.html

Comment: my question is ,application how much drain battery.suppose gmail application run in background so,how much battery drain by that app.i wann know drain level in percentage.